# How can I set up IP restrictions for "Azure REST API"?

Tags: azure

Is there any way to setup IP restriction for "Azure REST API"?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/

I am hoping there is a way to restrict IP access to an specific private VNET or IP range

Answer (score 0):

While you have no control over the API endpoints that Microsoft manages, you can control who logs into your specific tenant.  This is done through [**Azure AD Conditional Access**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/overview) policies.  Conditional Access can restrict access to:

- Specific Users/Groups
- IP Locations
- Devices
- Applications
- Real-time calculated risk detection
- Microsoft Defender for Cloud Apps

A sample policy that controls access to specific locations can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-location